# How does the store credit work?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

As a login bonus on day seven, you get a store credit. If I remember correctly, it was for a x3 Multiplier on Earth.

However, when I enter the shop I see no mention of that credit, nor is the x3 Multiplier free.

So, how do I access my reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the multiplier is applied directly and added to whatever multipliers you had before getting the day 7 login bonus.

So, if you had a *x12 Earth Multiplier* before logging in that day, you will see a *x15 Earth Multiplier* in the shop after accepting your reward.

There's no need to exchange that "credit" for the real stuff.